# Unable to import Swift class in Objective-C code in a framework project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have a framework project that has both Swift and Objective-C code. I am unable to import or use Swift class inside Objective-C code. This issue is happening in a framework project. I didn't face this issue in other non-frameworks projects.

Comment: Does the Swift class inherit from an Obj-C class or via @objc? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795117/when-to-use-objc-in-swift/46496642

Comment: @EricS I tried this.. but its not working for me.

Comment: Are you adding "YourModuleName-Swift.h" to the objective class?

Comment: @EmreÖnder Yes I am.

Comment: "Always Embed Standart Swift Libraries" option in build settings is No or yes?

Comment: Add header file for use of objective c file in project. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093069/xcode-how-to-include-c-library-and-header-file-to-cocoa-project

Comment: @EmreÖnder that option was set to "No". Changing it to "Yes" didn't work though.

Comment: can you clean the project and build it again after import statement added?

Comment: is framework added from pod or custom added by you?

Comment: Custom added. The issue is in the framework source code itself though.

Comment: see this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24102880/8687925

Answer (score -1):

1. create a swift class in you project then automatically show alert create bridging header file create option.
2. swift file import in bridging header file
3. user your swift file in objective c